# Does the FormValidation Plugin free

Tags: javascript, formvalidation-plugin

I'm trying to use [FormValidation](https://formvalidation.io) Plugin to my application, I followed the [guide](https://formvalidation.io/guide/getting-started/) but the validation does not work, so I'm wondering if the plugin is not a free, Because in their website you cant download the dist files, but the files exist [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/formvalidation).

Answer (score 2):

The Website states that the current/paid Version is on Version `1.9.0` while the Version on the CDN seems to be a [6-year-old](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formvalidation) `0.6.2-dev` Version which probably was published by accident or was just a very old dev Version.

Nothing on the Website indicates a free Version and the License attached to the CDNs header also indicates that it's only to be used after buying a license.